# Melt output unexpected , all 0 values

Tags: r, reshape2

Here is the following dataframe with only one row. In most cases the dataframes comes with many rows but came across one special case where i had only one row.

```
library(reshape2)
  temp <- structure(list(D0 = 0, D2 = 0, D14 = 0, D14 = 0, D14 = 8.1210458037618, 
D14 = 16.4531432694911, D7 = 0, D0 = 0, D0 = 0, D14 = 0, 
D0 = 0, D14 = 0, D7 = 12.9742361276578, D0 = 9.38010319990484, 
D14 = 6.35545262547878, D2 = 0, D14 = 1.35569798573994, D7 = 13.340409178823, 
D2 = 9.36805417941219, D2 = 15.432692223528, D14 = 0, D0 = 0, 
D14 = 0, D7 = 6.09471835659014, D7 = 0, D2 = 0, D2 = 7.67135586471563, 
D14 = 28.1073822991286, D14 = 0, D2 = 7.58819062711938, D7 = 0, 
D0 = 1.5735281713825, D0 = 0, D7 = 1.86165503278318, D7 = 5.35571350639711, 
D2 = 2.47400939410094, D14 = 21.3059220365934, D0 = 0, D7 = 8.69569412672166, 
D0 = 0, D14 = 0, D2 = 0.531180424946459, D0 = 3.42867314180642, 
D0 = 0, D2 = 0, D14 = 0, D7 = 0.775767964360802, D0 = 2.59382750787083, 
D7 = 0.600664752805997, D2 = 7.35512462974749, D14 = 2.30110773119572, 
D7 = 3.23850639812659, D0 = 0, D7 = 0.958981742285896, D2 = 3.84623208865623, 
D2 = 2.70323099283864, D7 = 1.65260222673919, D0 = 0, D2 = 4.00782923944589, 
D7 = 5.65802187007992, D0 = 0, D0 = 0, D7 = 0, phylum = structure(1L, .Label = "Acidobacteria", class = "factor")), row.names = 14L, class = "data.frame")

    > temp
       D0 D2 D14 D14      D14      D14 D7 D0 D0 D14 D0 D14       D7       D0      D14 D2      D14       D7       D2
    14  0  0   0   0 8.121046 16.45314  0  0  0   0  0   0 12.97424 9.380103 6.355453  0 1.355698 13.34041 9.368054
             D2 D14 D0 D14       D7 D7 D2       D2      D14 D14       D2 D7       D0 D0       D7       D7       D2
    14 15.43269   0  0   0 6.094718  0  0 7.671356 28.10738   0 7.588191  0 1.573528  0 1.861655 5.355714 2.474009
            D14 D0       D7 D0 D14        D2       D0 D0 D2 D14       D7       D0        D7       D2      D14       D7 D0
    14 21.30592  0 8.695694  0   0 0.5311804 3.428673  0  0   0 0.775768 2.593828 0.6006648 7.355125 2.301108 3.238506  0
              D7       D2       D2       D7 D0       D2       D7 D0 D0 D7        phylum
    14 0.9589817 3.846232 2.703231 1.652602  0 4.007829 5.658022  0  0  0 Acidobacteria
```

I´m running a melt function to aggregate data by phylum as follows (this will be next used to plot data with ggplot)

```
> reshape2::melt(temp,id="phylum")
         phylum variable value
1 Acidobacteria       D0     0
2 Acidobacteria       D2     0
3 Acidobacteria      D14     0
4 Acidobacteria       D7     0
```

How comes i only get 0 values ??? I would expect the sum of all D0 for Acidobacteria and all D2 for Acidobacteria and so on

```
> sum(temp[,colnames(temp) =="D0"]) 
[1] 16.97613

1 Acidobacteria       D0     16.97613
2 Acidobacteria       D2     60.9779
3 Acidobacteria      D14     83.99975
4 Acidobacteria       D7     83.99975
```

Comment: They are duplicated because they represent patients at three different time points. Is that the problem ?

Comment: Please mention any packages you're using in your actual question (don't assume that adding a tag will give that particular info) and what is your expected output exactly?

Comment: Also, your data appears wrong between `structure(...)` and `temp`. Notice that there are multiple `phylum` values in the assignment code, but only one value shows up in the output.

Comment: @brittenb The structure provided does reproduce temp.  phylum was most likely a factor and they were just giving a sample of the data. But all the levels of the factor will show up when using dput unless you drop the unused levels beforehand.

Comment: I have updated the dataframe by removing useless factors

Comment: @Dason Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't aware of that behavior. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @david... thanks but you still need to clarify on what your expected output is.  melt is doing as instructed. If you want something else then tell us what you're expecting.

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: Not really what i want. Have updated the expected output

Comment: Note that your column names wouldn't typically get created when making a data.frame because it wants unique names.  You can force it to make them unique by making a data.frame out of your data.frame (sounds silly but yeah...) `temp <- data.frame(temp)` will 'uniqueify' your column names. The melt will go through and afterwards you can convert the variable column back to what you actually want and then summarize.  Not the cleanest approach but your data isn't organized the cleanest at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're looking for requires a three-stage process: 1) rename the variables, 2) melt the data, 3) aggregate the data. We do this with the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages (or `reshape2` if you're keen on that package).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp <- structure(list(D0 = 0, D2 = 0, D14 = 0, D14 = 0, D14 = 8.1210458037618, 
                       D14 = 16.4531432694911, D7 = 0, D0 = 0, D0 = 0, D14 = 0, 
                       D0 = 0, D14 = 0, D7 = 12.9742361276578, D0 = 9.38010319990484, 
                       D14 = 6.35545262547878, D2 = 0, D14 = 1.35569798573994, D7 = 13.340409178823, 
                       D2 = 9.36805417941219, D2 = 15.432692223528, D14 = 0, D0 = 0, 
                       D14 = 0, D7 = 6.09471835659014, D7 = 0, D2 = 0, D2 = 7.67135586471563, 
                       D14 = 28.1073822991286, D14 = 0, D2 = 7.58819062711938, D7 = 0, 
                       D0 = 1.5735281713825, D0 = 0, D7 = 1.86165503278318, D7 = 5.35571350639711, 
                       D2 = 2.47400939410094, D14 = 21.3059220365934, D0 = 0, D7 = 8.69569412672166, 
                       D0 = 0, D14 = 0, D2 = 0.531180424946459, D0 = 3.42867314180642, 
                       D0 = 0, D2 = 0, D14 = 0, D7 = 0.775767964360802, D0 = 2.59382750787083, 
                       D7 = 0.600664752805997, D2 = 7.35512462974749, D14 = 2.30110773119572, 
                       D7 = 3.23850639812659, D0 = 0, D7 = 0.958981742285896, D2 = 3.84623208865623, 
                       D2 = 2.70323099283864, D7 = 1.65260222673919, D0 = 0, D2 = 4.00782923944589, 
                       D7 = 5.65802187007992, D0 = 0, D0 = 0, D7 = 0, phylum = structure(1L, .Label = "Acidobacteria", class = "factor")), row.names = 14L, class = "data.frame")

# Append a suffix to the column names to make them unique
names(temp) = paste0(names(temp), '_', 1:ncol(temp))
# Melt the data
temp = gather(temp, key='variable', value='value', -phylum_64)
# Could alternatively use melt(temp, id='phylum_64')
# Remove the suffixes from the column names
temp$variable = gsub('_\\d+', '', temp$variable)
# Group by the prior column names and sum the values
temp = temp %>%
    group_by(variable) %>%
    summarise(value = sum(value))

  variable    value
1       D0 16.97613
2      D14 83.99975
3       D2 60.97790
4       D7 61.20697
```